# ajax not working .No alert shown after submission

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to insert a name into my database. There is a form asking to enter name.There is also a submit button.on clicking the submit button no alert is show.I am new to ajax.

this is index.php.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").submit(function() {
                var name = $('#name').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: "name=" + name,
                    success: function() {
                        alert("sucess");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

This is ajax.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            $query=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
            mysql_select_db("freeze",$query);
            $name='l';//$_POST['name'];

            mysql_query("insert into tt values('','$name')");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your `ajax.php` you don't need to use html tags. You're able to see your dynamic calls through Chrome or Firefox Development tools (press F12 and go to console or network tabs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with url's in ajax. Your url is 'ajax.php', this is a relative url, so, if your page is at url http://localhost.com/index.html (for example), ajax will fire a post to http://localhost.com/index.html/ajax.php (and that's probably wrong). Try use absolute url, for that, add '/' at begin of url, then ajax will be fired against http://localhost.com/ajax.php.

Your ajax code should look like code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").submit(function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax.php",
            data: "name=" + name,
            success: function() {
                alert("sucess");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried as you said  http://localhost.com/ajax.php.Now it is working fine .thanks. Ricardo Silva

Answer (score 0):

The `submit` event is triggered on the `form`, not the submit button. So

```
        $("#submit").submit(function() {
```

will not ever be triggered, because `#submit` selects the button, not the form. You need to give an ID to the form:

```
<form id="myform">
```

then use

```
        $("#myform").submit(function() {
```

You also need to use `event.preventDefault()` or `return null` in the event handler, to prevent the form from being submitted normally when the function returns.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? If you set a breakpoint in the function, does it hit it?

Comment: can you please be kind enough to tell how to set breakpoints.What i have done is installed firebug and added debugger in the code and tested it.I got a syntax error as missing } i rectified it .but still data is not getting populated in database

Comment: thanks barmar .now the issue is solved.it was giving in giving path.